# React CSS module polluting the global namespace

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use CSS modules in my create-react-app (it's post 2.0.0 react-scripts, so that is not the cause of my problems).

Specifically, I'm trying to use bootstrap CSS to use components from an existing project into my own, rather than rewriting those components using react-bootstrap. These components are already written using vanilla bootstrap classes.

However, despite prefixing the .css to become bootstrap.module.css, the import statement seems to bring the rules into global scope, ruining the style of the rest of my page. Any ideas why this might be happening?

I import the css module like:

```
import style from './bootstrap.module.css'
```

Here's how I assign the style to the existing components:

```
<p className={style.lead}>
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 
</p>
```

Accessing the classes as attributes of 'style' doesn't even work - it looks like I can only do the traditional string based classing:

```
className="lead"
```

I'm not sure what code I could show that would be relevant, but let me know if you'd like to see something.

Comment: Hi could you provide some sample of your code?

Comment: Just added a little snippet of my import - let me know if you'd like to see anything else. Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes please show an example of how you "assign" those styles to one of your components

Comment: Added, but my problem is that these 'module 'styles are affecting components that aren't explicitly styled at all

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your webpack is not configured properly, you must specifiy an css loader in your webpack config as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                      sourceMap: true,
                      modules: true,
                      localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    }
                },
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if we're using react-scripts where the web pack config is handled by react-script?  I think?

Comment: By using  react-scripts  I assume you mean your using create-react-app? If so, the docs mention how to do this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/